# Пару синглтон объектов в одном скрипте . Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

К сожалению, я не смог передать  полностью в заголовке ,то что хочу сделать.
Есть пару объектов ,которые должны быть одиночками(синглтонами).
Скрипт синглтонов:

```
 public static UnitySingleton Instance { get; private set; }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            Instance = this;
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том , что таких объектов у меня много и каждый раз делать скрипт не хочу.
Есть один вариант:
Сделать несколько публичных объектов и синглтонов

```
public static UnitySingleton Instance { get; private set; }
public static UnitySingleton Instance2 { get; private set; }



public GameObject first;   
  public GameObject second;
```

Потом просто делать так

```
 private void Awake()
        {
            if (Instance)
            {
                Destroy(first);
            }
            if (Instance2)
            {
                Destroy(second);
            }
            else
            {
                DontDestroyOnLoad(first);
                Instance = this;
            }
        }
```

Вот только код работать не будет и нуждается в правке.
1.Этот фрагмент вряд ли будет работать так как нужно

```
public static UnitySingleton Instance2 { get; private set; } 
  public static UnitySingleton Instance2 { get; private set; }
```

2.Чем мне заменить Instance = this? (У меня же будет пару объектов);
3.Как сделать
`if (!= Instance2)` ?
 Думаю ,вы меня поняли.Нужно сделать противоположное
  `if (Instance2)`(Просто else здесь не будет работать как нужно.)

Comment: вы что-то делаете не так, применение синглтонов, вещь исключительная и требующая большого внимания при кодировании. Опишите пожалуйста, для чего вам нужны эти синглтоны, возможно вам дадут гораздо более изящный ответ!

Comment: У меня есть много уровней (сцен) и 3-4 объекта которые есть на каждом уровне.Что бы их не создавать каждый раз на сцене я решил сделать из них синглтоны.

Comment: Что мешает хранить эти "3-4 объекта" в одном Singleton классе?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Возможно, я что-то не так делал , но когда пытался хранить эти "3-4 объекта" в одном Singleton классе , то все кроме одного объекта удалялись.

Comment: Скорее всего, я не смог нормально реализовать из-за моего незнания.

Comment: @Veudd Используйте всего один синглтон с этим скриптом, а объекты добавляйте в него как дочерние и уже без скрипта.

Comment: @trollingchar Я просто должен в окне иерархии сделать остальные объекты дочерними?

Comment: @Veudd да. Нужен пустой объект-родитель со скриптом синглтона. Те объекты, которые должны всегда быть, перетаскиваем в него и у них этого скрипта не должно быть.

Comment: Это сработало .